# Controlling cucumber tags in hooks.rb file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm running some tests where I need a new browser session to start for every scenario within an Example Table format.  I've managed to achieve this by using the following in my hooks.rb file:

```
if ENV['kill_session']
 After do |scenario|
  Capybara.current_session.driver.quit
  end
end
```

This works well but I only want it to run for tests that contain a certain tag, @payment to be precise.

I've tried the following to try and only invoke it when a scenario has the @payment tag, not for every test in the pack:

```
if @payment == true
  After do |scenario|
    Capybara.current_session.driver.quit
      end
    end
```

This hasn't worked.  I'm sure it's a simple solution but so far it's eluded me.  The tests are being run via Selenium_Webdriver.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upon reading a little further, I found what I needed and as expected, it was simple.  I thought I'd post it, should anyone else need it in future.

```
After('@payment') do
  Capybara.current_session.driver.quit
end
```

Simple.